# My program appears to stop working

Tags: processing

I am quite new to programming and decided to make a little game, so far I have only made a small block that is able to move in all 4 directions (left, right, up and down). Pretty simple  and nothing extra-ordinary. However, when I run my program, sometimes it will stop working, not as in crashing causing Processing itself to crash, but my program will just end.

As far as my testing goes, I think this happens when I press two keys at the same time (like W and S). Does anyone happen to know what causes it to stop, and perhaps how to fix it as well?

```java
void setup(){
  size(1080,720);
  frameRate(30);
}
int shipLR = 0; //Variable for the ship to go left/right
int shipUD = 0; //Variable for the ship to go up / down


void draw(){
  background(0);
  shipLR = constrain(shipLR, 0, 1040); //Constrain the ship in the window
  shipUD = constrain(shipUD,0,680); // Constrain the ship in the window
  move();
  Shuttle();
}

void Shuttle(){
  rect(shipLR, shipUD, 40,40); //Draw the ship
}

void move(){
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a') {
      shipLR = shipLR - 20; // Go left
      return;}
    if (key == 'd') {
      shipLR = shipLR + 20; // Go right
      return;}
    if (key == 'w'){
      shipUD = shipUD - 20; // Go up
      return;}
    if (key == 's') {
      shipUD = shipUD + 20; // Go down
      return;}
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I found something that causes this problem to occur more frequent; If I implement a frameRate of a value lower than 60 (currently trying with 30) this happens more often.

Edit 2: With the suggestions below of making my move function in a single if block had a lot of good impact. The program no longer stops when I move the ship in the middle of the window it no longer stops, it now only does it at rare occasions when I bump too often against the borders of the window. Perhaps it has something to do with constrain?

Comment: This is not the entire program, could you post more? It doesn't look wrong I think

Comment: But it is the entire program. And as far as I can see, I don't see anything that is wrong either.

Comment: It can't be. There must be at least a main, otherwise this couldn't work.

Comment: Did you try to use only one (keypressed) block? Java also provides try catch blocks you should wrap the content of your method and print the error using  e.printStackTrace()

Comment: @Goot that is a good idea for improvement but I doubt it will solve the problem

Comment: its worth a try, since  keyPressed seems to be managed by processing.

Comment: Another approach - is it allowed in processing to draw a rectangle outside of the current Window? You don't check if the current position of the rectangle is inside the view

Comment: I edited the program and updated the post in a way that the move function is in one block (thanks for the suggestion). However, as for the main function, I wouldn't know where to find it, because this is literally everything I have in my Processing window. @Goot, and yes it is allowed to draw a rectangle outside of the current Window, however I tell my program to not do that with the double constrain in my draw function.

Comment: @Bruus so the program is not entirely yours, hmmm... Well, you should try to find the main function and everything else, because there's literally nothing wrong (speaking of execution only) in what you've posted

Comment: @Shinratensei It is, but I am using Processing as IDE, maybe that has something to do with it. Anyway I managed to reduce the frequency of this bug by a large enough margin that it no longer poses as a huge issue.

Comment: Doesn't processing have a loop class or something? Can you post everything you have in the processing window?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by stop working? The window closes? The block stops responding to key presses?

Comment: @Shinratensei This is processing, not Java, even though processing is based on java, it doesn't follow everything that java does, this here is complete code in processing, main method is not written/required in processing

Comment: @Shinratensei Please note the [tag:processing] tag. Recommended reading: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).

Comment: @KevinWorkman oh, ok, thank you for that. I really didn't know anything about that. Very counter intuitive, it's clear now. I'm sorry for everything.

Comment: I tested your source using the current version of processing and it actually didn't crash. - Download the current version of processing. Also run it using the command line so you might have a chance to catch some errors delivered by processing. Good Luck.

Comment: @Goot I don't think OP's problem is that it's crashing. I think that the problem is they're pressing the wrong key. Please see my answer for what I think is going on. And how exactly do you propose running Processing via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

in `move()` (java naming conventions specify that method names start with lower case) you should exit on the first key pressed found.  the code can be re-organized to reduce multiple identical conditions:

```
void move(){
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a') {
      shipLR = shipLR - 20; // Go left
      return;
    }

    if (key == 'd') {  // still inside if keyPressed
      shipLR = shipLR + 20; // Go right
      return;
    }

    if (key == 'w') {
      ...
    }
  }  // end of if keyPressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I edited the move function as you suggested, and it greatly improved, but alas the program still stops working after a while.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that the program doesn't "stop working" or end- it's just that your rectangle stops moving. If you let go of all the keys, then push just one key, I'd bet that the rectangle starts moving again. (In the future, please try to be more specific- saying "it stops working" isn't very helpful.)

Anyway, that's because of the way you're handling the key presses. What happens if you press a key other than the ones you're checking for?

You'll enter the `move()` function, and you'll enter the `if(keyPressed)` block, but you won't enter any if the other `if` statements inside that block. The `key` variable only holds the most recently pressed key.

Depending on what you want to do, you should either refactor those `if` statements to only **change** the direction if the key was valid, and to ignore all other key presses. Or you might want to use a set of `boolean` variables to track multiple keys being pressed at the same time. More info on that approach can be found [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input).

If you still can't get it working, then please try to be more specific about exactly what happens.